# To load excel file in R/ R studio

Tags: r, excel, csv

My questions are:

I am able to read the file using read.csv but read.table gives me an error. I've also tried the following codes, but failed to read the file:

```
read.table("hw1_data R programming.xlsx", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

read.table("hw1_data R programming.xlsx", sep = ",")

read.table("hw1_data R programming.xlsx", header = TRUE, sep = ",",fileEncoding='UCS-2LE')
```

How can I use `read.table`?

- What are the advantages (or disadvantages) of using `read.table` over
  `read.csv` and vice versa? [I belive one point is: `read.table` don't require files to be saved in csv format, which is the case generally. Am I right?]
- I've googled for ways to load excel file in R and found http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-import, http://www.statmethods.net/input/importingdata.html and tried installing gdata (and also with xlsx). And finally was able to load the file. But I wonder, why do we need all these steps installing packages like gdata/xlsx/etc...perl) , if we can simply do the same thing by `read.csv` or `read.table`.
  What are the advantages (or disadvantages) of using these packages over `read.table` and `read.csv` and vice versa?

Comment: Have you already tried to open a .xls file in a text editor? This can give you an idea, why packages are needed for this operation.

Comment: I've already tried doing the same. I can open a csv file with text editor but other formats like xls and xlsx shows some encrypted text, which is not under-stable. But my question is why these packages are better than read.csv, if they are?

Comment: There are several packages for reading excel files: *readxl*, *openxlsx* or *xlsx*.

Comment: I am not asking about the available packages. My query is about the comparative advantages/ disadvantages of these packages over read.table and read.csv.

Comment: .xls has not a plain text format (hence my first comment) and R doesn't understand its file's structure. Therefore, you need packages to help R interpret what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
install.packages("readxl")
library(readxl)
hw1 <- read_excel("hw1_data R programming.xlsx")
```